# Initialize a PCL PointCloud::Ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, point-cloud-library

This is very likely s a simple thing, but I am stuck. I am trying to initialize a Point Cloud Library Point cloud in a header file, so that I can share it across functions.

I am trying:

//.h

`typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::POINT_TYPE> PointCloud;`

`PointCloud::Ptr currCloud;`

//.cpp

`currCloud= new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>;`

But this gives me

`no operator '=' matches these operands`

How can i initialize this type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PCL, the point types have to match between declaration and definitions.

Change

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::POINT_TYPE> PointCloud;
```

to

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> PointCloud;
```

In your header.

Comment: Thank you! i have made this change, and now get: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  no suitable user-defined conversion from "pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>" to "boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>>" exist`

Comment: i have also tried: `currCloud= new PointCloud::Ptr;`, with the same error

Comment: It's because you're attempting to initialize a boost shared pointer using "new". Try using: currCloud= pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);